# Single Table Inheritance and Unknwon column in field list

Tags: mysql, hibernate, inheritance

I have a problem with single table inheritance in Hibernate and MySQL.
My code is simple:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="VEHICLE_TYPE")
@Table(name="VEHICLE")
public abstract class Vehicle {

  @Id
  @Column(name="VEHICLE_ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long vehicleId;

  @Column(name="MAKE")
  private String make;

  @Column(name="MODEL")
  private String model;

  //setters and getters
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Vehicle {

  @Column(name="BODY")
  private String body;

//setters and getters
}
```

I also have a service to get all cars:

```
@Override
public List<Car> getCars() {
    TypedQuery<Car> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Car c", Car.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

When I run the app and try to get a list of Cars I get the following console output:

Hibernate: select car0_.VEHICLE_ID as VEHICLE_2_6_, car0_.MAKE as MAKE3_6_, car0_.MODEL as MODEL4_6_,car0_.BODY as BODY7_6_ from VEHICLE car0_ where car0_.VEHICLE_TYPE='Car'

WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'car0_.BODY' in 'field list'

Hovever, my table model has this column in place and this service used to work fine without inheritance.
Any ideas what do I miss?

Comment: did you try to execute the output SQL into the DB itself (i.e. thru Workbench)? and did you get same result?

Comment: good point. It doesn't work, I get the same error: Unknown column 'car0_.BODY' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should check the definition of your VEHICLE table if it indeed includes the BODY column. The error suggests that it does not have such column. Maybe you need to re-create your table or manually update your table definition to include that column. If you are using the hibernate property hbm.ddl.auto in your hibernate config or persistence.xml, set it to UPDATE to update the schema.

Comment: Vehicle doesn't have BODY column, it's intended to be Car's property only. This is the way I want it to work: vehicle properties are shared between all vehicles while Body is only for a Car.

Comment: I'm talking about your physical table VEHICLE and not your entity class. Since you are using Single table strategy, both of your Vehicle and Car entity classes are mapped to just one table - which is the VEHICLE table. The BODY column should also be in the VEHICLE table. That's is how Single Table strategy works.